# Function not running after using strtok

Tags: c, c-strings, strtok

I'm having some trouble in my program after using `strtok()`. I have tested `printf` and the `opt` is always getting what it is supposed to. But when i reach the if clauses, nothing runs. For example, when i type `a banana` it should run the function a1, but the program just ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char pedido[80],*opt

int main(){
    fgets(request,80,stdin);
    opt=strtok(request," ");
    if (opt=="a"){a1();}
    if (opt=="q"){a2();}
    if (opt=="N"){a3();}
    if (opt=="A"){a4();}
    if (opt=="r"){a5();}
    if (opt=="R"){a6();}
    if (opt=="C"){a7();}
    if (opt=="p"){a8();}
    if (opt=="E"){a9();}
    if (opt=="m"){a10();}
    if (opt=="l"){a11();}
    if (opt=="L"){a12();}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by return the function a1().  It does not look like a1 is defined to me.  What does a1 do?

Comment: @Hogan it is defined, i just didnt include it in the question because the issue isnt in the function itself

Comment: @user3121023 Its not supposed to run because banana has an a, it is because the first character is an a. What is typed after the space will be used in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements like this

```
if (opt=="a"){a1();}
```

do not make sense because the opt can never be equal to "a". The value of opt is either NULL or the address of a character in the array request. As the string literal and the array occupy different extents of memory then their addresses are not equal.

You should use the standard C function strcmp as for example

```
if ( strcmp( opt, "a" ) == 0 ){a1();}
```